# How to write unit test for return text.Split

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Dear all I'm trying to unit test this code, but it keeps failing.

```
public string[] StringArray(string text)
{
    return text.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Select(x => x.Remove(0, 1).Remove(x.Length - 2, 1)).ToArray();
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than
>   zero. Parameter name: startIndex

I'm a little bit new to this and tried already a lot of options, but the test keeps failing. Does someone have any suggestions?
This is the test i've written and maybe it is all wrong, but i think the error is maybe in my input?
Would really appreciate some help.

```
[TestClass]
public class ContextHelperTests
{
    private ContextHelper _instance;
    private string _removeText = "4, 324, 123";
    private string[] _expectedOutput1 = new string[] { "4", "324", "123"};

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _instance = new ContextHelper();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ContextHelper_ItemsInOutput_RemoveText()
    {
        // Arrange
        var expectedResult = new string[] { "4", "324", "123" };

        // Act
        var result = _instance.StringArray(_removeText);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("4, 324, 123", result.Length);
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(result, _expectedOutput1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your split looks to be a lot more complicated that necessary. `string.Split(", ")` would actually suffice for your test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Remove(x.Length - 2, 1)
```

For "4" the length is 1 so 1-2 = -1. According to the exceptions table in the [documentation for String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx), this parameter should be greater than 0. You wanted to drop 2 characters from a string that has only one.

Comment: If you want to drop the first and the last character (I'm guessing that's what "x.Remove(0, 1).Remove(x.Length - 2, 1)" is for), then yes. You will need at least 2 character long numbers for input.

Comment: @Shan's Your code cannot handle this input - but if it should your code is wrong

Comment: I also agree with Sir Rufo.

Comment: If my input is 2 character long, I get this error: 
    Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<123, 000 (System.String)>. Actual:<2(System.Int32)>.

Answer (score 0):

Your test fails because you have this `Remove(x.Length - 2, 1)` and in your test data you have string with length=1 - is `"4"`.
Not sure why you using Remove here, try this function

```
public string[] StringArray(string text)
{
    return text.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
}
```